# Return code 1 in gulp-sonar 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, gulp, sonarqube

I have gulp-sonar 3.0.0 with Sonarqube 5.3 and JavaScript plugin version 2.10.we get the following error in our build scripts:

> 11:42:44] 11:42:44.510 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>
> [11:42:44] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Report processing is
>   taking longer than the configured wait limit. at
>   org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.QualityGateBreaker.getAnalysisId(QualityGateBreaker.java:165)
>   at
>   org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.QualityGateBreaker.execute(QualityGateBreaker.java:108)
>
> [11:42:44] Return code: 1.
>
> /development/workspace//node_modules/gulp-sonar/index.js:74
>   throw new PluginError('gulp-sonar', format('Return code: %d.', code));
>   ^ Error: Return code: 1.

Any idea how can I fix this issue?

Comment: How can we help you?

Comment: First upgrade to SonarQube 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured build breaker plugin timing out because sonar is taking too long to process the request. increased the wait time and now working fine.